# automatically stop scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs after n function calls (not BFGS iterations!)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, regression

I use logistic regression with **scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs** for minimizing the cost function. The cost function stays constant for my particular data set and BFGS does not converge, so I want to apply lasso+ridge regularization.

Now, I want to try out optimizing the cost for various values of the regularization parameters lambda1/2 in order to find the best combination:

```
for lambda1 in range(...):
    for lambda2 in range(..):
        scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(...) # Optimize cost with lambda1 and lambda2
```

The problem is that, because BFGS is not converging, it stays "forever" in the call for the first values of lambda1/2.

Is there a way to automatically stop fmin_bfgs after a while? The **maxiter** parameter does not help me, because I have 1000s of samples and a large number of features/sample, so it doesn't even finish one such iteration in acceptable time.

In scipy 0.11, fmin_bfgs has a **maxfun** parameter -- can one emulate this somehow in scipy 0.10?

**EDIT: By popular demand, here are some relevant snippets of code:**

The function computing the cost (the usual notations apply):

```
def computeCost(theta, X, y):
    h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta.T))
    J = y.T.dot(log(h)) + (1.0 - y.T).dot(log(1.0 - h))
    J_reg2 = theta[1:]**2
    J_reg1 = theta[1:]
    cost = (-1.0 / m) * (J.sum() + LAMBDA2 * J_reg2.sum() + LAMBDA1 * J_reg1.sum())
    return cost
```

Invoking the fmin_bfgs function:

```
initial_thetas = numpy.zeros((len(train_X[0]), 1))
myargs = (train_X, train_y)
theta = scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(computeCost, x0=initial_thetas, args=myargs)
```

Comment: A workaround way would be to add a sort of number of calls counter to the function itself and `raise` a special exception when the desired number of calls is reached.

Comment: @Zhenya Thanks! I was hoping there might be an easier way, but I might end up doing that.

Comment: @Denis What do you mean by "delta X"? I have my training samples in X, no modifications are done to them.

Comment: sorry, theta: print theta, cost to see how they're moving, or deltas theta - theta prev, cost - costprev

Comment: @Denis Aha, ok! Well, the problem is that the cost changes infinitesimally (around 8th decimal place or so), so it practically stays the same. I made a rather extensive post with my source code and outputs [here on Cross-Validated.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27050/how-to-find-parameters-for-ridge-and-lasso-regularization-when-cost-minimization).

Comment: @Cristina, will look. Print also the two parts of J -- one or the other log(sigmoid) may be huge ?

Comment: @Denis y*log(h)~=-200, (1-y)*log(1-h)~=-1314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't the number of iterations. The reason why the lambda numbers aren't changing is that the optimisation isn't working.
Scipy should be working out those numbers for you rather than you supplying them through for loops.

Maybe if you could include more code it would be easier to see how to fix it.

Comment: But I am optimizing against the theta values (the cost is a function of the thetas), not the lambdas! How could I get the lambdas as well from the bfgs?

Comment: You should be able to add lambdas and thetas as part of x0, then split them at the beginning of the compute cost function

Comment: So I would present to the BFGS for optimization, instead of J(theta), J(theta,lambda)?